# Laravel validation ErrorException - htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I'm new to laravel 5, and just started writing my own app.

When i just call the route for the invoices.create controller, the view generates just fine.

When i redirect to that same view from the invoices.store controller, I'm getting following error message.

[image: erorr message]

My controller, looks like this.

[image: controller]

I'm guessing it's conflicting with the parameters passed to the controller, looking at the message. But I can't seem to find whats wrong and how to solve it.

EDIT:
This is the view...

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">New Invoice</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @if ($errors->has())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        {{ $error }}<br>        
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                @endif

                {!! Form::model(new App\Invoice, array('route' => array('invoices.store'))) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('customer_id', 'Choose customer:') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('customer_id', array(null => ' - Please select customer - ') + $customers, $selected_customer, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="company_row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('number', 'Number:') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('number', $invoice_number, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('date', 'Date:') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('date', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Invoice items</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="table-invoice-items">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th>VAT</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="cell-width-5">{!! Form::text('items[amount][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
                                            <td>{!! Form::text('items[description][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
                                            <td class="cell-width-6">{!! Form::text('items[price][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
                                            <td class="cell-width-5"></td>
                                            <td class="cell-width-12">{!! Form::text('items[vat][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
                                            <td class="cell-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pointer" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-invoice-item">New Item</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('note', 'Note:') !!}
                        {!! Form::textarea('note', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::submit('Create Invoice', ['class'=>'btn primary']) !!}
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#date").datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

    $("button#add-invoice-item").click(function(){
        var table_row = $("table#table-invoice-items > tbody > tr:first").clone();
        table_row.find('input:text').val('');
        $("table#table-invoice-items > tbody > tr:last").after(table_row);
    });
});
</script>

@endsection
```

Okay so i managed to narrow the problem down. It has something to do with arrays as name for the input field, when i delete this table row.. the error is gone.
But how do i solve this?

```
<tr>
    <td class="cell-width-5">{!! Form::text('items[amount][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::text('items[description][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
    <td class="cell-width-6">{!! Form::text('items[price][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
    <td class="cell-width-5"></td>
    <td class="cell-width-12">{!! Form::text('items[vat][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}</td>
    <td class="cell-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pointer" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This looks like the problem might be in the view. Please post that code by editing your question. And don't post it as an image but rather just (correctly formatted) text. This way it's searchable and readability on many devices can be guaranteed.

Comment: Edited the post as you asked

Comment: Is it possible that `invoice_number` is an array and not just a number? Try `dd($invoice_number)` in the controller.

Comment: You don't appear to actually set the `invoice_number` in the `store()` method, but you do in the `create()` method which is probably why it works there.

Comment: @JoelHinz, i don't quite get that... There is a redirect to create, so the create controller gets called again?

Comment: @lukasgeiter there is no way that getInvoiceNumber returns an array I'm afraid...

Comment: @JoelHinz `store()` doesn't even render the view. It makes a redirect...

Comment: @Yordi Hmm. You could try and remove/comment out parts of the view and try to track the error down this way...

Comment: I tracked down the problem... see my edit... 
But what's the solution i wonder... 
I don't know how else to do inputs with arrays as name.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This is known issue with Laravel's form builder: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2243

It prevents you from using an array as the name parameter of a Form::text() method call. I think it has to do with how the form assigns values from the given model in the HTML.

I think you're going to have to write basic HTML form stuff for that part.

Comment: Please check the bottom of my post, i tracked down the problem.
I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked you're debugging notes. I did some more digging into the issue and found something. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for looking this up. 
However this is a problem that dates from 2013 going from that link.
I would like to see how multiple rows are done in laravels form builder and how they are validated, but i can't seem to find anything. Maybe i'm just using the wrong words in my search, idk.

Comment: The last comment in the discussion I linked to was from Taylor Otwell, the creator or Laravel. I believe this issue is still unsolved and they have no plans in the future to implement a fix. In fact, Laravel 5 does not include the Form builder by default.

Comment: it actually anything other than input file , it will give error when using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Hm I've managed to reproduce the problem. I have an file array field:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" />
```

And I am also trying to get the old value field like this:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" value="{{ old('files') }}" />
```

As I found this causes the error with the htmlentities() for some reason. If someone has time to inspect this case, please write your results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `[]` in the form field names, assign an integer `[1]` and increment.

For example, this:

```
{!! Form::text('items[amount][]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Would be:

```
{!! Form::text('items[amount][1]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Further reading: 
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/form-array-validation-in-laravel-5-2#a-quick-introduction-to-html-form-arrays